#include не видит файл
хеддер vector2.h описан в

root/core/math/...

основной файл main.cpp описан

root/main/...

могу предположить, что ошибка в том, что main.cpp не в root директории, но не уверен.





Заменить:
#include "core/math/vector2.h"

на
#include "../core/math/vector2.h"

P.S: Спасибо за -1 голос
